# Errors when changing MySql for PostgreSQL in Java with Hibernate App

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I try to migreate my app from MySql to PostgreSQL. It just a very small app in which I'm working on. Just 5 or 6 tables.

So I recreate the same database in postgresql, I learnt that the user word is reserved for postgress and that the Primary Key needs to be Serial type.

So after some minor adjustment, Hibernate was working I can recreate the models directly from the db.

The first Issue that I have is that when I try to store something it added 0 as PK. So as in Java a "null" int is 0 (or let say, an unassign int is 0) when I get that object from the database (which PK is 0) and I'm creating a new object, it give me the error:

```
A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

This is how I stored the entities.

```
public Object addOrUpdate(Object item) throws Exception {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(item);
        return item;
    }
```

After some google, I change `saveOrUpdate` for `merge`, but although I didn't get that error,  all the values where replacing the the first one (which has PK 0). So I di end in the database the last object was the one that was stored.

This is my table:

[image]

The id (the last column) was created as BigSerial.

And this is the model in Java created by Hibernate from my postgresql

```
@Id

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

I'm using Java1.8 and PostgreSQL 10.

So how I can keep using postgresql but avoid having those issues?

Comment: "*that the Primary Key needs to be Serial type*" - no they don't "need" to be that. But if you want auto-incrementing numeric primary key, then yes, `serial` or `identity` is the way to go.

Comment: There are many questions around Hibernate and auto-incrementing primary keys in Postgres: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+%5Bhibernate%5D+serial+

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I said that needs to be Serial type because of the incremental... so how can I reject postgresql using 0 as PK?

Comment: A Postgres sequence does not start with `0` (at least not the sequence created by a `serial` column) so that value is most probably generated by your obfuscation layer because it doesn't know that the column is auto-generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add additional annotation if you want support auto increment in hibernate.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;
```

The generated value annotation is required to auto increment the values. 
There are four different types of generation strategies.

1) GenerationType.AUTO

2) GenerationType.IDENTITY

3) GenerationType.SEQUENCE

4) GenerationType.TABLE

Refer to the following link for explanation

https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! Is there any way to let Hibernate added automatically with PostgreSQL? with MySQL I didn't have to do any manual change in the models.

Comment: You may have add the generation type identity in your model class to use the autoincrement in postgresql

Comment: Since your table size is only 6 it should be simple to add to all model classes

Comment: Yes, for now it is... but the idea is that the model will grow and changes can occurs, so each time I have a change in the structure of the DB, I will need to add manually one line to each model (and also import the required classes for that line). Which I now is not so much work, but I'm use to use mysql where that problem didn't exist. Anyway, your answer was what I was looking for.. so thank you very much!